# Add lines to the beginning and end of the huge file

Tags: shell-script, files

I have the scenario where lines to be added on begining and end of the huge files.

I have tried as shown below.

- for the first line:

  ```
  sed -i '1i\'"$FirstLine" $Filename
  ```
- for the last line:

  ```
  sed -i '$ a\'"$Lastline" $Filename
  ```

But the issue with this command is that it is appending the first line of the file and traversing entire file. For the last line it's again traversing the entire file and appending a last line.  Since its very huge file (14GB) this is taking very long time.

How can I add a line to the beginning and another to the end of a file while only reading the file once?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`sed -i` uses tempfiles as an implementation detail, which is what you are experiencing; however, prepending data to the beginning of a data stream without overwriting the existing contents requires rewriting the file, there's no way to get around that, even when avoiding `sed -i`.

If rewriting the file is not an option, you might consider manipulating it when it is read, for example:

```bash
{ echo some prepended text ; cat file ; } | command
```

Also, sed is for editing streams  -- a file is not a stream. Use a program that is meant for this purpose, like ed or ex. The `-i` option to sed is not only not portable, it will also break any symlinks to your file, since it essentially deletes it and recreates it, which is pointless.

You can do this in a single command with `ed` like so:

```bash
ed -s file << 'EOF'
0a
prepend these lines
to the beginning
.
$a
append these lines
to the end
.
w
EOF
```

Note that depending on your implementation of ed, it may use a paging file, requiring you to have at least that much space available.

Comment: Hi, ed command which u provided  is working very well for huge files. But I have 3 huge files like Test, Test1, Test 2. I gave command like ed -s Tes* << 'EOF'
0a
prepend these lines
to the beginning
.
$a
append these lines
to the end
.
w
EOF

But its taking only Test file and adding first/last lines. How can we make changes in same command so that it has to do add first and last line in all files.

Comment: @UNIXbest - Use a `for` loop: `for file in Tes*; do [command]; done`

Comment: Hi Down, i have used below command for file in Tes*; do  
ed -s Tes* << 'EOF'

0a
HEllO HDR
.
$a
Hello TLR
.
w
EOF
done
But its still writing into first file.

Comment: Right, because you need to use `"$file"`, not `Tes*` as the argument to `ed`.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the command , its working as expected.

Comment: @UNIXbest If your problem has been solved by this answer, you should consider accepting it.

Comment: @ChrisDown: How does deleting and recreating a file break *symlinks*? It breaks hard links, for sure, but symlinks are link-by-name, not link-by-inode.

Comment: @rici `echo foo > bar; ln -s bar baz; sed -i 's|foo|bar|' baz` -- note that `baz` is no longer a symlink. This happens because `sed -i` moves the temp file on top of the old file.

Comment: @ChrisDown: that's fair enough, but I don't think it's covered by "break symlinks *to* your file". "break if your file is a symlink" would be more precise IMHO. Also, with GNU sed at least, you can use `-i --follow-symlinks` to avoid precisely this problem.

Comment: @rici Which introduces a whole bunch of other problems.

Comment: Hi Down,
for file in File_Name*
        do
                ed -s $file << 'EOF'
                0a
                $Header_Record
                .
                $a
                .
                w
                EOF
        done

The above command is executing in the unix box but is not when I write it in script file.

Is there another format for this?

Comment: If you want `$Header_Record` to be expanded, you need to unquote `'EOF'`, but then you need to escape `\$a`.

Comment: ok. I have few condition where i have to add only header records or trailer records to files. can we  achieve that using same command?
I tried same ed command for adding only trailer records to file, but on top of every file(Header place) its adding  space. How can we add only header or trailer using same ed command.?

Answer (score 9):

Note that if you want to avoid allocating a whole copy of the file on disk, you could do:

```
sed '
1i\
begin
$a\
end' < file 1<> file
```

That uses the fact that when its stdin/stdout is a file, `sed`  reads and writes by block. So here, it's OK for it to override the file it is reading as long as the first line you're adding is smaller than `sed`'s block size (should be something like 4k or 8k).

Note though that if for some reason `sed` fails (killed, machine crash...), you'll end up with the file half processed which will mean some data the size of the first line missing somewhere in the middle.

Also note that unless your `sed` is the GNU `sed`, that won't work for binary data (but since you're using `-i`, you are using GNU sed).

Comment: this errors for me on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 4):

Here are some choices (all of which will create a new copy of the file so make sure you have enough space for that):

- simple echo/cat

  ```
  echo "first" > new_file; cat $File >> new_file; \
    echo "last" >> new_file;
  ```
- awk/gawk etc

  ```
  gawk 'BEGIN{print "first\n"}{print}END{print "last\n"}' $File > NewFile
  ```

  `awk` and its ilk read files line by line. The `BEGIN{}` block is executed before the first line and the `END{}` block after the last line. So, the command above means `print "first" at the beginning, then print every line in the file and print "last" at the end`.
- Perl

  ```
  perl -ne 'BEGIN{print "first\n"} print;END{print "last\n"}' $File > NewFile
  ```

  This is essentially the same thing as the gawk above just written in Perl.

Comment: Note that in all of these cases, you will require at least 14GB more space for the new file.

Comment: @ChrisDown good point, I edited my answer to make that clear. I assumed that was not a problem since the OP was using `sed -i` which creates temp files.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the much simpler:

```
gsed -i '1s/^/foo\n/gm; $s/$/\nbar/gm' filename.txt
```

This transforms the file:

```
asdf
qwer
```

to the file:

```
foo
asdf
qwer
bar
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to insert data at the beginning of a file¹, all you can do is create a new file, write the additional data, and append the old data. So you'll have to rewrite the whole file at least once to insert the first line. You can append the last line without rewriting the file however.

```
sed -i '1i\'"$FirstLine" $Filename
echo "$LastLine" >>$Filename
```

Alternatively, you can combine the two commands in one run of sed.

```
sed -i -e '1i\'"$FirstLine" -e '$ a\'"$Lastline" $Filename
```

`sed -i` creates a new output file and then moves it over the old file. This means that while sed is working, there is a second copy of the file using up space. You can avoid this by [overwriting the file in place](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87772/add-lines-to-the-beginning-and-end-of-the-huge-file/87780#87780), but with major restrictions: the line you're adding has to be smaller than sed's buffer, and if your system crashes you'll end up with a damaged file and some content lost in the middle, so I strongly recommend against it.

¹  <sub>Linux does have a way to insert data into a file, but it can only insert a whole number of filesystem blocks, it can't insert strings of arbitrary lengths. It's useful for some applications, such as databases and virtual machines, but it's useless for text files.</sub>

Comment: Not true. Look at `fallocate()` with `FALLOC_FL_INSERT_RANGE` available on XFS and ext4 in modern kernels (4.x.x) http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html

Comment: @Eric You can only insert whole blocks, though, not arbitrary byte lengths, at least as of Linux 4.15.0 with ext4. Is there a filesystem that can insert arbitrary byte lengths?

Comment: Right but it still doesn't make your statement correct. You wrote: "There is no way to insert data at the beginning of a file". That's still not true: there is a mechanism to insert extents at the beginning of a file. It comes with caveats, sure, but it's worth mentioning because some users may not care about the block size restrictions by filling with spaces or carriage returns.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '1i|ALFA' -c '$a|BRAVO' -cx file
```

1. `1` select first line
2. `i` insert text and newline
3. `$` select last line
4. `a` append text and newline
5. `x` save and close

Comment: what if we wanted to do this to multiple files?

Comment: @geoyws that is not really in scope for this question

Comment: are you sure that is $a and not %a?

Comment: This one appears to temporarily use a .swp file on disk. You need enough space for the .swp file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ (echo "Some Text" ; cat file1) > file2
```

Comment: Only code answer are not acceptable, please improve your answer

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to include an explanation of your suggestion, or links to documentation which support your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Linux kernels (higher than 4.1 or 4.2) support inserting data at the beginning of a file via the `fallocate()` system call with `FALLOC_FL_INSERT_RANGE` on ext4 and xfs filesystems. In essence this is a logical shifting operation: the data is logically relocated at a higher offset.

A constraint exists regarding the granularity of the range you want to insert at the beginning of the file. But for text files you can probably allocate a little more than required (up to the granularity boundary) and fill with spaces or carriage returns, but that depends on your application

I don't know of any readily available linux utility that manipulates file extents but it isn't difficult to write: get a file descriptor and call `fallocate()` with the appropriate arguments. For further details, refer to the man page of the `fallocate` system call: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html

Comment: A utility isn't the problem (assuming a non-embedded Linux): util-linux contains a `fallocate` utility. The problem is that a granularity of whole blocks makes this useless for most text files. Another problem is that the range allocation and subsequent modification are not atomic. So this doesn't actually solve the problem here.

Comment: The granularity is a caveat I've mentionned already and no, it doesn't make it useless, it depend on the application. Where did you see in the question that atomicity is important? I can only see the problem of performances. Even so this syscall seems to be atomic: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/open.c#L228 and if atomicity becames important (it isn't, but say it is for the sake of argument) then just use file locking. (point me to the place in the kernel code where `fallocate` atomicity is broken please, I'm curious)

Comment: I think it's a viable solution if the IO constraints are firm (huge file, little space, speed...). Also picked up here - `fallocate --insert-range` https://stackoverflow.com/a/65206144/481812

Comment: ...and I guess it's worth mentionaing that only few filesystems can support this.

Comment: It's alreay mentionned that only few filesystems can support this if you read the answer.