# Adding text to beginning of text file

Tags: sed, text-formatting

I am trying to add a line of text to the beginning of a text file (Actually not text, but just two backslashes).
I am trying the following, which I found in this answer: [Add lines to the beginning and end of the huge file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87772/add-lines-to-the-beginning-and-end-of-the-huge-file)

```
$ sed -i '1i\'"$\\" $Simdata.txt
```

However, I cannot seem to get it to function.
When I use the above, I get the error:

```
sed: 1: ".txt": invalid command code .
```

I have tried without the txt ending, but then I get this error:

```
sed: -i may not be used with stdin
```

I also tried this line of code, which I found somewhere else:

```
$ sed -i '1i \\' Simdata.txt
sed: 1: "Simdata.txt": invalid command code S
```

UPDATE:

@don_crissti, your first solution is what I want to do. However, it does not seem to function as intended.

```
$ cat Simdata.txt
abcdefghijkabcdefghijk
//
abcdefghijkabcdefghijk
$ sed '1i\
> \\\\' Simdata.txt
\\abcdefghijkabcdefghijk
//
abcdefghijkabcdefghijk
$ cat Simdata.txt
abcdefghijkabcdefghijk
//
abcdefghijkabcdefghijk
```

So the file is not updated. I would prefer not to print the file, just update the file or print to a new one. Also, I made a silly typo: I would actually like to add two forward slashes.
What I am ultimately aiming at doing is the following.

I have a file looking like this:

```
abcdefghijkabcdefghijk
//
abcdefghijkabcdefghijk
//
abcdefghijkabcdefghijk
```

I want to first add // to the beginning of the file:

```
//
abcdefghijkabcdefghijk
//
abcdefghijkabcdefghijk
//
abcdefghijkabcdefghijk
```

And then add a unique name after each //:

```
// text 1
abcdefghijkabcdefghijk
// text 2
abcdefghijkabcdefghijk
// text 3
abcdefghijkabcdefghijk
```

and save this to a new file, without changing the original file. So the above question was aiming at figuring out the first step.

Comment: If you want to print to another file just add `>outputfile` after the command, e.g. `sed '....' mytextfile >outputfile`. If you want to update the existing file use `-i` e.g. `sed -i '...' mytextfile` or  `sed -i.bak ... mytextfile` if you want to make a backup copy of your original file.

Comment: Perfect! That seems to work! Thank you.
However, it does not insert a new line, but just adds \\ to the beginning of the original first line. Do I need to add \n?

Comment: That doesn't work either.
The files are mac-made.

Comment: Yes! That works! Can you explain the logic to me?
If I want to insert // and not \\, which backslashes do I change to forward slashes in the code?

Comment: You just escape those as well, e.g. `sed '1s/^/\/\/\'$'\n/' mytextfile` (escaping means adding a backslash before the character has to be escaped). For the `\'$'\n` part, see [this](https://nlfiedler.github.io/2010/12/05/newlines-in-sed-on-mac.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the backslashes (so four backslashes will insert two literal backslashes):

```
sed '1i\
\\\\' my_text_file
```

or

```
sed '1s/^/\\\\\n/' my_text_file
```

The first one will insert a new line containing two backslashes at the beginning of your file, the second one will substitute the beginning of the first line (`^`) with two backslashes followed by a `\n`ewline (same result).
With `osx sed`:

```
sed '1s/^/\\\\\'$'\n/' mytextfile
```

Comment: don_crissti, your first solution is what I am trying to do. I have updated my above question with the attempt to use your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add two `\\` to the beginning of a file then [this](https://superuser.com/a/246841) should work:

```
echo '\\' | cat - todo.txt > temp && mv temp todo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '\\\\' > newfile.txt; cat oldfile.txt >> newfile.txt
```