# Unix: Add unique names after signs in text

Tags: text-processing

I have a file looking like the following:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
//
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
//
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
```

I use the following code to insert a line with // to the beginning of the document (as advised here: [Adding text to beginning of text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181418/adding-text-to-beginning-of-text-file?noredirect=1#comment302179_181418)), and save this update to a new file.

```
sed '1s/^/\/\/\'$'\n/' File_1.txt > File_2.txt
```

What I would like to do, however, is to add unique names after each //, getting a result like this:

```
// Text 1
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
// Text 2
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
// Text 3
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
```

etc.

I was thinking I could use tr to translate eg. "//" into "// Text 1".
But how do I add Text 2 to the next //, text 3 to the third // etc.?
 The txt file is mac-osx made.

UPDATE:

Your solution looks good, @PM 2Ring, however, I have the addiditional problem, that the file actually looks like this:

```
// 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstu 
//            x   x 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstu 
//          x   x 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
```

So the name is perfectly inserted in first line, but after the secons pair of /, the name is inserted after x, at the end of the line. I need to insert the name just after //, but without shifting the remaining text to the right. Is it possible to delete the same amount of spaces, as the there are characters in the name? This should then not be done in the first line, of course, as I assume this would delete characters from the second line.

Comment: The question is: Where do these unique texts come from? Counting would be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=1}; /\/\//{$0=$0 " Text " n; n+=1}; {print}' infile
```

If `infile` contains

```
//
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
//
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
//
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
```

The above command prints

```
// Text 1
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
// Text 2
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
// Text 3
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
```

The cryptic-looking `/\/\//` is a regex (a `Reg`ular `Ex`pression) containing `//`. In awk regexes are delimited by the forward slash `/`; to put forward slashes into a regex you need to escape them with the backslash `\`.

In awk, *pattern*{*action*} says perform *action* if the current line matches the *pattern*. The `BEGIN` pattern is a special pattern to signify actions we want to happen before any lines are read. If we don't specify a pattern, the action is performed for all lines (although there is a way to override that).

---

This updated version will sort-of work on your new input file, but unfortunately it won't preserve the spacing

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=1}; /^\/\//{$1=$1 " Text " n; n+=1}; {print}' infile
```

**input**

```
// x  x
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
//    x    x
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
//          x   x
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
```

**output**

```
// Text 1 x x
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
// Text 2 x x
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
// Text 3 x x
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
```

Comment: You can do `n+=1` (or `n++`) before `$0=...` to exclude `BEGIN{n=1}`

Comment: @Costas: Good point, but I decided to use explicit initialisation of `n` to make it easier for people unfamiliar with awk to understand, and to make it easier for them to modify the starting number, if desired.

Comment: **awk** do not require variable pre-initializaton. And so as we try to use ideologicaly right patterns I'd like to offer `{n++ ; $(NF+1)="Text" ; $(NF+1)=n}` instead of your `{$0=$0...}`

Comment: @Hjalte Try to exchange `$0` to `$1`

Comment: This is what I am aiming at, thank you! I have some additional trouble, however. I have updated my question above.

Comment: @Costas: I understand that `awk` does not require variable pre-initializaton; I use that feature frequently. But I like your `$(NF+1)="Text" ; $(NF+1)=n`. Do you think it's more efficient than `$(NF+1)="Text " n` ?

Comment: I suppose it is not more efficient but ideologically true.

Comment: @Hjalte: As Costa said, you _could_ change my command to `'BEGIN{n=1}; "//"{$1=$1 " Text " n; n+=1}; {print}'` however, that will mess up the spacing. Preserving the spacing in the way you describe in your edited question requires a slightly more sophisticated script and I don't have time to work on it tonight.

Comment: Okay, no problem, thank you for your help!
To clarify: when using the original code you posted, I actually get a unique name after every single line, not just after the // line.
With the @Costas edit, I get names only after // lines, but with everything moved to the left (only single spaces between each text, instead of several as in the original file).

Comment: @Hjalte Try `awk -F '' '/\/\//{n++ ; t=" Text "n ; sub("// {0,"length(t)"}","//"t)}{print}' File_2.txt`

Comment: Sorry @Hjalte, my 2nd example doesn't work properly; I must've mis-read the output when I tested it. :embarrassed: But the 1st one should only append the `Text ...` stuff to lines that contain `//`. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: just use `$0 ~ "//"` and everything be OK ;) In my case (with `-F ''`) it can be `$1$2 == "//"`

Comment: @Hjalte: If nobody's posted a satisfactory solution that handles the spaces properly, I'll have a look at this again tomorrow. But it's getting really late in this timezone. :)

Comment: @Hjalte See 4th comment above. It can be workable.

Comment: @Costas, we are getting so close! The code is removing one space to much. So the remaining text on the line is being shiftet one single space to the left. Can I correct that?

Comment: @Hjalte It is not true. You can check the string length before and after substitution `{n++ ; t=" Text "n ; printf ("%d = ",length()) ; sub("// {0,"length(t)"}","//"t) ; print length()}` But if you like change script to `... sub("// {0,"length(t)-1"}", ...`

Comment: When I test it on my data, I do get a single shift to the left. Weird. The  length(t)-1 works perfect, though. Thank you very much!
When I run the script, I do get a message saying: `awk: field separator FS is empty`. Is that something I need to worry about?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `perl`, and the evaluation flag to increment a variable in the replacement part. It search for every line that begins with `//` and appends `Text` followed by a number:

```
perl -pe 's{\A(//)}{$1 . " Text " . ++$i}e' File_1.txt
```

It yields:

```
// Text 1 
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
// Text 2 
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
// Text 3  
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
```

---

#### **Update** (see comments):

Do grouping on the spaces after `//` and calculate the number of spaces to insert in the replacement part, like:

```
perl -pe 's{\A(//)(\h*)}{$1 . " Text " . ++$i . " " x ((length ($2)) - length(" Text " . $i))}e' temp
```

Using your last example, it yields:

```
// Text 1
abcdefghijklmnopqrstu 
// Text 2     x   x 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstu 
// Text 3   x   x
abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
```

Comment: This works very good, thank you!
Do you have an idea for a soloution for my updated problem above?
Your solution inserts the unique name perfectly after //, but also shifts the remaing text to the right. Is it possible to avoid this? So delete as many spacings as characters inserted?

Comment: @Hjalte: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Converting @Birei solution to the "additional trouble" update:

```
perl -pe 's{^// {10}}{sprintf("// Text %-3d ",++$i)}e  or
          s{^//     }{sprintf("// Text %d",   ++$i)}ex '          infile
```