# Bash - How can I add a string to the beginning of a text file without reading all of it?

Tags: text-processing, sed, out-of-memory

i'm trying to insert a string "hello world" before of a text file named "test.txt", i already do it with sed, but unfortunately "sed command" kill my memory, because it reads a entire file.

my file contains a text with 1gb size, and my memory have only 512 mb.
how i can do it?, something like this:

```
echo --insert-before "hello world" >> test.txt
```

Or which operator i have to use to insert it before, something like this:

```
echo "hello world" << test.txt
```

Or another idea?

Note: the operator `>>` to insert text at end works fine, it not kill my memory, but i need to do it in reverse for the start of the file, without override the contents of my text file, without new line.

here is my actual code that i used:

```
echo "hello world" > test.txt;
echo "the large content that size is 1gb" >> test.txt;
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' test.txt;
```

Comment: Have you tried using an intermediate file? Like `{ echo hello world; cat test.txt; } >file && mv file test.txt`

Comment: "cat command" kill my memory too :(

Comment: but i will try with your suggest, await...

Comment: What sed command did you use?

Comment: this command: `sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' "test.txt"`

Comment: i was trying a replacement of line break `\n`, after insert a text at beginning of file

Comment: related https://superuser.com/questions/246837/how-do-i-add-text-to-the-beginning-of-a-file-in-bash and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87772/add-lines-to-the-beginning-and-end-of-the-huge-file

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, already see it before, i've not found any solution for my circumstances...

Comment: Is the file on a "ramdisk", which typically means somewhere which is mounted on a tmpfs filesystem? If so how much swap space do you have and is it possible to increase it?

Comment: @ilkkachu if you are going to translate the tile from spanish to english then do it, or don't. (I finished the job for you)

Comment: Sorry by delay, i was taking breakfast... im here again.

Comment: Icarus, im working in a cloud, i don't have access to increase the size of the memory, my plan are basic  512mb ram, 5gb storage.

Comment: Guys, thanks by the support, solution already found, Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that the sequence of commands you used was:

```
echo "hello world" > test.txt;
echo "the large content that size is 1gb" >> test.txt;
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' test.txt;
```

I will assume that the commands were actually:

```
echo "hello world" > newfile;
cat test.txt >> newfile;            # assuming the file with 1GigaByte was test.txt
```

And you complaint about the sed command, which is only there to remove newlines (from your description).

The same could be done with `tr` which doesn't use (much) memory:

```
echo "hello world" > newfile;
cat test.txt | tr -d '\n' >> newfile
```

And `newfile` will have a copy of test.txt with "hello world" prepended.

Comment: Works perfect, merged in a single line without kill the memory, and adding a text before of the content of 1gb.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` does not use much memory. However the OS may be caching disk. Therefore using `nocache` may help (If disk is fast enough, or you are not reading the same data more than once). And/or use the `--unbuffered` option of `sed` (so that `sed` rely does use as little memory as it can).

Also there can be no option to echo, as `>>` is done by the shell, not the command. It tells the shell to append the stdout of the command to the file.

And as @Kusalananda says your `sed` script is not efficient. I would probably just use cat.

```
uncache cat "<(echo the_prefix)" old_file_name > new_file_name
rm old_file_name
mv -T new_file_name old_file_name #note not all `mv`s have the `-T` option, it can unsafely be left out.
```

Comment: thanks by the observation

Comment: But unfortunately i got a error "sed line 3 killed", and the memory are full in the end and after be killed the ram are emty again.

Comment: I added a bit about how to make `sed` use less memory.

Comment: Note that their `sed` script is reading the whole file into the pattern space.

Comment: I found a solution using vim according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46792629/6005145): *This should be faster, since vim won't read whole file when process.* Would this be a good answer? I ask because I'm not familiar with vim, and OP should install it. Thanks

Comment: thanks, im here again, i will try again your method, wait some secs pls.

Comment: method checked, i can't understand what are you doing, not works clearly for me... explain me pls, uncache command makes cat not store buffers in memory?

Comment: Thanks by all answers... i appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be forced to read the whole file to add anything to the front of the file.  However, you don't have to read it into memory, which is what your `sed` command is doing.

The easiest solution would be to simply concatenate the new contents with the existing file to create a new file, and then replace the original file with that:

```sh
printf '%s\n' "new contents" | cat - test.txt >new-test.txt
mv new-test.txt test.txt
```

Here, `cat` would first read from its standard input stream (from `printf` or whatever other command you may choose to use), and then from the old `test.txt` file.  The output would go to the file `new-test.txt` (which would be created, or truncated if it previously existed).

If you absolutely must use `sed` for this:

```
sed '1i\
new contents
' test.txt >new-test.txt &&
mv new-test.txt
```

This triggers an insert (`i`) command on the first line of the file, and inserts the new contents before it.  Then the rest of the old file is outputted.  The result, as before, is written to `new-test.txt`, which later could replace the original file.

Would you want to do an in-place edit, and have GNU `sed`, you could write it a bit neater:

```
sed -i '1i new content' test.txt
```

With GNU `sed`, you could insert multiple lines using `\n` as newlines:

```
sed -i '1i new content\nsecond line' test.txt
```

With standard `sed`, you'd be doing

```
sed '1i\
new content\
second line
' test.txt >new-test.txt &&
mv new-test.txt test.txt
```

Comment: checking it, await pls...

Comment: already checked, unfortunately the text is breaked by a new line...

Comment: @Policy478 According to your question, this is what you want. You said you wanted `echo something >>file` but with the new text added to the start rather than the end. Or do you mean you get a _blank_ line somehow?  Let us know if all you want is to modify the first line of the file or add lines to the start of the file.

Comment: I've specified without new line, at the end of my question, but no worries thanks by your question...

Comment: @Policy478 That text can be interpreted as you want to insert a text with no newlines (i.e. a single line) as the first line of an existing text.  The "without override the contents of my text file" would otherwise be impossible to achieve as you would have to _modify the first line_.

Comment: exactly without remove the content, but in the same line, NO LINE BREAKS, but i apologize, maybe i'm not much specific...

Comment: Thanks by all answers... i appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

How about something a bit simpler?

```
cat <<_eof_ > file
Hello world!
$(cat file)
_eof_
```

Or use ed

```
echo '0a
your text here
.
w' | ed some_file
```

Comment: I will try your method, too... waits some secs pls...

Comment: Even worse. The shell will keep whole content of `file` in memory until it completes expansion of here-doc

Comment: i hate the browser code formatting; each should be a separate line but stack mangled it

Comment: Sorry, ed command not found, which package i have to install in ubuntu or debian?

Comment: Thanks by all answers... i appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

If this is killing your memory:

```bsh
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' "test.txt"
```

then, to remove newlines but only read one at a time, try:

```bsh
{
    printf "hello world"  # with no newline
    while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
        printf "%s" "$line"
    done < test.txt
    echo ""          # add a newline to the end of the file
} > test.txt.tmp && mv test.txt{.tmp,}
```

This will be a bit slower than sed, in normal circumstances, but your situation is out of the ordinary.

Comment: Wouldn't a `cat test | tr -d '\n' >>test.tmp` be a bit faster ?

Comment: I'm sure it would, but I'm trying to minimize what's in memory at any one time.

Comment: Im checking your method, wait some secs pls...

Comment: In which way(s) does tr use more memory than a variable holding a whole line (which could be long) ? @glennjackman

Comment: Processing a 1GByte file: `Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 1716`, seems reasonable to me. @glennjackman

Comment: Thanks by all answers... i appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you can install `vim` here is a possible solution. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46792629/6005145) I was caught up by this:

*This should be faster, since vim won't read whole file when process.*

> NOTE: I'm unfamiliar with `vim` so please backup your data before
>   trying. In my tests it works.

```
vim -es +'1s/^/foo/' +'wq!' test.txt
```

I'm willing to delete the answer if there are problems that I'm unaware of.

Comment: checking it too, wait some secs...

Comment: Thanks by all answers... i appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new file containing 'hello world', and then append the 1gb file's content into that using DD (which won't read the entire file at once).

```
echo -n 'hello world' > new_file.txt | dd if='1gb.txt' of='new_file.txt' bs=1 seek=$(wc -c <new_file.txt) && rm 1gb.txt
```

Source: https://jamesdanielmarrsritchey.blogspot.com/2019/11/memory-friendly-way-of-prepending-data.html